# Magento 2 catalog_product_alert schedule entries not being created

Tags: magento2, schedule, cronjobs, stock-alert

All store configuration is properly setup, the cron is running, everything else is working, but there are no **catalog_product_alert** schedule entries being generated or *back in stock alerts* sent.

I have only found one curiosity, the *core_config_data* table includes the following setting:

`crontab/default/jobs/catalog_product_alert/run/model : NULL`

I suspect there should be some value there, but i cant seem to find any clues to what that value could be and i suspect this is part of the issue that no cron schedule is being created.

The following link helped understanding the issue, but provided no solution so far:
https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Product-Stock-Alerts-Not-Sending/td-p/43032

Comment: I had this exact issue, and spent hours trying to find a solution to my alerts not firing, but it turns out everything was running correctly. I had just assumed it wasn't working because I couldn't see catalog_product_alert in the cron tasks. But this is because it only appears once per day, as per the time you select in the admin settings. But the issue for me was that the server time was 1 hour ahead. so setting it to 10am didn't work at 10am, but it did fire at 11am. So because i kept setting the time of the alerts to 10mins from my current time, it was never firing and I was constantly cha